# React - Looping through an object full of arrays that contain an object

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I've set the state to a very large piece of JSON that has an object full of different arrays, inside of these arrays is an object.  I am trying to loop through this to set the image property inside the latter object as another piece of state and make the entirety of my JSON accessible.

[Screenshot of my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJ2Ax.png)

[Screenshot of the JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKz9T.png)

```
   import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
   import ImageCard from "./components/ImageCard";
   import ImageSearch from "./components/ImageSearch";

   function App() {
   const [image, setImages] = useState([]);
   const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState([]);
   const [term, setTerm] = useState("");
   const [person, setPersons] = useState([]);

   useEffect(() => {
   fetch(`http://localhost:4000/persons`)
   .then((res) => res.json())
   .then((data) => {
    setPersons({ person: data });
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }, [term]);

    return (
    <div className="container mx-auto">
    <ImageSearch searchText={(text) => setTerm(text)} />

     {isLoading ? (
     <h1 className="text-6xl text-center mx-auto mt-32">Loading...</h1>
      ) : (
     <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4">
      {console.log(person.person)}
     </div>
     )}
     </div>
     );
     }

     export default App;
```

> This is as far as I'm able to get through this.

Visual representation of a piece of the state.

```
{
  "Current Age From": 60,
  "City Of Last Contact": "Newport",
  "First Name": "John",
  "Modified Date Time": "2018-05-09T12:52:08-05:00",
  "Middle Name": "Marcus",
  "Last Name": "Gatens",
  "image": "https://public.opendatasoft.com/api/v2/catalog/datasets/namus-missings/files/bad52b8084bd4e61f0114a88739c7463",
  "Current Age To": 60,
  "Computed Missing Max Age": 37,
  "Computed Missing Min Age": 37,
  "County Of Last Contact": "Lincoln",
  "id Formatted": "MP37393",
  "Race / Ethnicity": "White / Caucasian",
  "Date Of Last Contact": "1995-05-31",
  "State Of Last Contact": "OR",
  "Gender": "Male",
  "link": "https://www.namus.gov//MissingPersons/Case#/37393",
  "namus2Number": 37393,
  "Geo Shape": "{\"type\": \"Point\", \"coordinates\": [-124.0534650116, 
   44.6367888754]}",
  "geo_point_2d": "44.6367888754,-124.053465012"
}
```

Also this is my first post and I've only been programming for a year and a half and still struggle with a lot of this. I've tried a spread operator and .map but still can't wrap my head around it.  I apologize if the information I provided does not suffice.

Comment: Can you post a representative sample of your state? For example, take the object full of different arrays, remove all arrays but one, then either insert the remaining JSON into your question, or put it into a GitHub Gist, and provide a link to the Gist. If the data is sensitive, feel free to modify names and any other personal information that there is.

Comment: I would have to drop a majority of the database to take out all of the arrays but one, the data is not sensitive it's a clearing house for missing people it's just very large. EDIT: I see what you're saying. I can do that yes one moment.

Comment: Pull the image from the each object of data array and push it into the images array. Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes, pushing all the Images into state would suffice.  I  want to loop through all 9052 items it contains so I can use anything from the object inside the array.

Comment: @JohnMorganBroaddusIV Yep, you can just grab a sample from the dev console. To preserve the original syntax though, you can also do this:

1. Right-click the data in the dev console, and select "Store as global variable". This will store your data in variable "temp1", and you can now refer to the variable from the console.

2. In the console, execute the following command: `copy(temp1[0])`. This will put the first array item from your data into the clipboard.

3. Paste it into your question.

Comment: @JuraGorohovsky Okay that was really cool to learn I had no idea that could be done. Thank you.

Comment: OK, if you're setting "person" to the entire data object that you've just fetched (`setPersons({ person: data })`), then setting "image" could be done like this: `setImages({image: data.map(item => item["image"])})`. I'm just not sure that's what you need. Since your state variable is called `person`, I figure you might want to set a particular person, not all of them, or else rename the state variable to `persons`?

Comment: @JuraGorohovsky - I have tried that its giving me "TypeError: data.map is not a function
    at App.js:22";  I have rendered the images before using a spread operator but have never been able to save them to state.

Comment: @JuraGorohovsky - figured it out, it was basically what you had given me. just with one more data `setImages({image: data.data.map(item => item["image"])})` Thank you so much how does this work like do I leave a review or do I set this as solved?

Comment: Good to know! The way it usually works is people post answers (instead of comments as above), and the asker marks one of them as accepted. Sometimes a discussion starts in comments to a question, and then when a solution emerges during the discussion, it's posted as an answer for the asker to accept. This is what happened here, and I'll post an extract of the comments as an answer that you can mark accepted.

Comment: Posted my comment as answer in its original form. On a different note, you might want to transform your incoming JSON so that you don't have to do this mind-breaking `data.data` thing.

Comment: @JohnMorganBroaddusIV FYI, this is what you're expected to do when your question is answered: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

If you're setting "person" to the entire data object that you've just fetched (`setPersons({ person: data })`), then setting "image" could be done like this: `setImages({image: data.map(item => item["image"])})`.